# write commands from windows 7 and in ubuntu server

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04

I am using `ubuntu server 16.04 lts` on lan. I can access to this via filezilla.

I want to ask you guys if is it possible to send command to ubuntu server from windows7 ?

I am using only cli. I did not install gui in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh that's simple :)

do the following

SERVERSIDE

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

Windows side!

install putty

With putty connect to the server using SSH, ofcourse you need the ip first of the server so on the server do ifconfig, put that in putty and you have a SSH tunnel to your server, you logon with your credentials and now you have a Linux cli on windows 7 that controls your server

Comment: i do not have admin pass for windows 7. is it other way ? i have also filezilla installed

Comment: the credentials of the server, sorry my bad!

Comment: i know credentials but i do not want to install anything in windows7

Comment: You could use this

https://serfish.com/console/

Comment: putty does not have to be installed. Just download putty.exe [here] (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or the complete package putty.zip and unzip it to any folder (e.g. your desktop), then start putty.exe

Comment: You are right, my bad, I have it stuck in my toolbar so it looks like its installed XD